# rvalue refrence of lvalue reference vs rvalue reference of lvalue/rvalue

Tags: c++, rvalue

Is it legal to have a rvalue refrence of a lvalue reference ?

Considering the following example, is there a difference between the two cases in the final rvalueRef in term of what it refer to or type (or others things)?

```
Type& ref = GetReference()
Type&& rvalueRef = std::move(ref)

vs

Type value = GetValue()
Type&& rvalueRef = std::move(value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both code is correct and 100% legal in C++. There is a difference only in the sense that in the first case a reference is moved (or better say, capable of being moved if appropriate destination is used) and in second case, it is the copy *(see the example below for clarification on this)*.

**Note that `std::move` does NOT actually move the object. It only casts the object into a rvalue reference type.** That is all.

Also note that in **both** cases, `rvalueRef` is *still* an lvalue — an object which has a name (i.e an identifier to refer to) is never an rvalue. So if you don't actually move it using `std::move` (or using explicit cast) again, then there is no difference at all.

Here is a concrete example:

```
//given function
std::string& GetReference(); 
std::string  GetValue(); 

//target function
void f(std::string param);
```

And your code follows:

```
std::string& ref = GetReference();
std::string&& rvalueRef = std::move(ref);

std::string value = GetValue()
std::string&& rvalueCopy = std::move(value); //named changed
```

till now NO DIFFERENCE at all.

But if you do this:

```
f(std::move(rvalueRef));  //actual object returned from GetReference is moved!
f(std::move(rvalueCopy)); //only a copy is moved.
```

The actual object is moved in the first case, and in the second case, the copy is moved. It doesn't make any difference at all if you do this:

```
f(std::move(GetReference()));  //actual object returned from GetReference is moved!
f(std::move(GetValue()));      //only a copy is moved.
```

So you see, in your code, there is no difference **because there is NO ACTUAL MOVE at all**. Only cast is there. To have an actual move, there should be an appropriate target type which could invoke move-constructor or move-assignment! In your case, there is NO invocation of either.

Answer (score 1):

**Q.** *Is it legal to have a rvalue refrence of a lvalue reference?*

That's not really the question you are asking. The question you are really asking is this:

**Q.** *Is it legal to cast an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference?*

The answer is yes. `std::move` just casts its argument to an rvalue reference, which is always legal. The overall correctness of what you are doing depends on what you then do with the *result* of `std::move`. There is nothing wrong with your example code.

**Q.** *Is there a difference between these two cases?*

```
// case 1                             // case 2
Type& ref = GetReference();           Type value = GetValue();
f(std::move(ref));                    f(std::move(value));
```

The only difference is that in case 1, `ref` is a reference to the object returned by `GetReference()`, but in case 2, `value` is a copy of the object returned by `GetValue()`.